# Android App's JavaDoc opens Android SDK Javadoc in 4 subframes instead of 1 is there a way to fix this?

Tags: android, javadoc

Update: I've now added screenshots since I'm no longer deemed a spambot.

Evidently I can't post screenshots as part of StackOverflow's "spam prevention mechanism", so you'll have to struggle through descriptions...

When you generate JavaDoc with a `"-linkoffline http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/ http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/"`, it makes nice links that open just the class's description inside your right frame - the same behavior that clicking links to one of your own classes has.

All *MY* Classes listed in left frame, Details of selected class in right Frame (i.e. java.lang.Object)

[image: Linked with Sun's JavaDoc]

When you generate JavaDoc with a `"-linkoffline http://d.android.com/reference C:\Android\android-sdk\docs\reference"`, if you click a link to say Object, instead of just opening the Object class in the right frame, it opens a page with 4 sub-frames inside your right hand frame.

All *MY* Classes listed in left frame, 4 sub-frames in right fram:  Android developers header (top), with package list (left top), class list (left bottom), and Details of selected class i.e. java.lang.Object (right)

[image: Linked with Android JavaDoc]

Is there a way to link your app's JavaDoc to Android's SDK JavaDoc so that it actually looks pretty and like one cohesive JavaDoc? i.e. is blue and have the standard 2 frame interface (like Sun's JDK documentation and default user generated documentation?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that what looks like a deep link into the Android reference, like http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html (as an example), in fact is not a only the documentation of this class, but also in fact contains what looks like different frames with the links to other packages. These are actually lists in the HTML source code, which are styled with some CSS and JavaScript too look like separate frames:

Here is the end of the package list and the start of the list of classes in one package:

```
 ...
 <a href="/reference/org/xml/sax/helpers/package-summary.html">org.xml.sax.helpers</a></li>
    <li class="api apilevel-1">
  <a href="/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/package-summary.html">org.xmlpull.v1</a></li>
    <li class="api apilevel-1">
  <a href="/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/sax2/package-summary.html">org.xmlpull.v1.sax2</a></li>
              </ul><br/>
            </div> <!-- end packages -->
          </div> <!-- end resize-packages -->
          <div id="classes-nav">
            <ul>

    <li><h2>Interfaces</h2>
      <ul>
          <li class="selected api apilevel-1"><a href="/reference/android/content/res/XmlResourceParser.html">XmlResourceParser</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><h2>Classes</h2>
      <ul>
          <li class="api apilevel-1"><a href="/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.html">AssetFileDescriptor</a></li>
          <li class="api apilevel-3"><a href="/reference/android/content/res/AssetFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream.html">AssetFileDescriptor.AutoCloseInputStream</a></li>
 ...
```

The actually important part is in the `<div class="g-unit" id="doc-content">` which comes after these navigation div's.

So I suppose you could use some Javascript to hide all the other divs and only show this one. Or, alternatively, show those links in the top frame instead of the current one.

There might be some modified version of Javadoc out there which produces documentation similar (and compatible to) the Android reference, but I don't know where.